# Date range display in views using PHP

Tags: datetime, views

How do I display date ranges for Value1 and Value2 in the following format where value2 is display as the difference between Value1 and Value2 expressed in days. I'd like to rewrite the results of a view field using PHP code.

Value1=1-Jan-2013

Value2=6-Jan-2013

i.e. result expected:

```
1-Jan-2013 +5d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date('d-M-Y', strtotime(value1));
$datetime2 = date('d-M-Y', strtotime(Value2));
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$result = $datetime1 . ' ' . $interval;
```

result will be
1-Jan-2013 +5d